# Comparison of LEFT JOINS in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

If I have a query structured as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TBL1.Name, TBL2.Month, TBL3.Month
FROM (TBL1
LEFT JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.Name = TBL2.Name)
LEFT JOIN TBL3 ON TBL1.Name = TBL3.Name
```

Produces a result such as:

```
TBL1.Name|TBL2.Month|TBL3.Month
-----------------------------
Name1    |7        |8
Name1    |8        |8
Name2    |8        |8
Name3    |8        |
Name4    |         |8
```

That first row's result is what is causing my problems. TBL3.Month needs to be NULL (or blank) because the month in TBL2 and TBL3 don't match.
The fourth row is accurate, there were no records in TBL3 for Month 8 so it accurately reflected NULL.
Likewise, The fifth row is accurately representing TBL2 missing data for Month 8.

The data in the tables is a simple format such as the following:

TBL1

```
Name
----
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

TBL2

```
Name  |Month
------------
Name1 |7
Name1 |8
Name2 |8
Name3 |8
```

TBL3

```
Name  |Month
------------
Name1 |8
Name2 |8
Name3 |8
Name4 |8
```

The desired output would look like the following:

```
TBL1.Name|TBL2.Month|TBL3.Month
-----------------------------
Name1    |7        |
Name1    |8        |8
Name2    |8        |8
Name3    |8        |
Name4    |         |8
```

Comment: You should provide sample data.

Comment: . . Please show the data you are starting with.

Comment: Sorry, I hope the update paints a clearer picture

Comment: I am also not opposed to using sub-queries in the query if the limitations of Access prevent a single query from working (i.e. nested select statements)

Comment: Using exact posted data and query in MS Access, I cannot reproduce the first set of results. I do reproduce your desired results except for row 4. Not sure why value is missing as there is a non-NULL value for `Name3` in `TBL3`. My guess is data is filled for `Name1`, `Name2`, and `Name4` in `TBL3` which reproduces original results. Please carefully check your data.

Comment: You're correct. I posted incorrect data. TBL3 should have had a row where Name1 and 8 were present. Corrected.

Comment: Using the data as posted now we get the original "problem statement"

Answer (score 0):

If you need for the months to match, include that in the `on` clause:

```
FROM (TBL1 LEFT JOIN
       TBL2
       ON TBL1.Name = TBL2.Name
     ) LEFT JOIN
     TBL3
     ON TBL1.Name = TBL3.Name AND TBL2.MONTH = TBL3.MONTH
```

The following *may* do what you want:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM (TBL1 LEFT JOIN
       TBL2
       ON TBL1.Name = TBL2.Name
     ) LEFT JOIN
     TBL3
     ON TBL1.Name = TBL3.Name
WHERE TBL2.MONTH = TBL3.MONTH OR
      TBL2.MONTH IS NULL OR
      TBL3.MONTH IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When structuring the query as you suggested (provided below) I get "JOIN expression not supported" as a popup error.

`
SELECT DISTINCT TBL1.[Name], Month([TBL2].[Date]), Month([TBL3].[Date])
FROM (TBL1 LEFT JOIN [TBL2] 
ON TBL1.[Name] = [TBL2].[Center Name]) 
LEFT JOIN [TBL3] 
ON TBL1.[Name] = [TBL3].[Center Name]
AND Month([TBL2].[Date]) = Month([TBL3].[Date])
`

Comment: Using the latest edit with the additon of the WHERE clause cuts off the first row